# Merge columns that are separated by character in order

Tags: r

I have a table that has two columns with information separated by ":". Te problem is that not all of them has the same size.

I'll write an example:

Col1              ol2

AA:BB:CC          1:2:3

AA:DD:BB:CC       4:5:6:7

And I would like a third column that is

Col3

AA=1:BB=2:CC=3

AA=4:DD=5:BB=6:CC=7

I've not idea where to start, I've try to split them, but it took me nowere

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strsplit` to split the 'Col1', 'Col2' by `:`, then concatenate the corresponding `list` elements with `str_c` to create the 'Col3'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(col3 = map2_chr(strsplit(Col1, ":"), strsplit(Col2, ":"),
      ~ str_c(.x, .y, sep="=", collapse=':')))
#      Col1    Col2                col3
#1    AA:BB:CC   1:2:3      AA=1:BB=2:CC=3
#2 AA:DD:BB:CC 4:5:6:7 AA=4:DD=5:BB=6:CC=7
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("AA:BB:CC", "AA:DD:BB:CC"), Col2 = c("1:2:3", 
"4:5:6:7")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```